# PersistentActor doesn't receive command

Tags: scala, persistence, akka

I have implemented the following PersistedActor

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.persistence._

object TaskDispatcher {

  /**
   * Create Props for the actor
   */
  def props(): Props = Props(new TaskDispatcher())

  case class AddEndpoint(serverEndpoint: ActorRef, id: String)
}

class TaskDispatcher() extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
  import TaskDispatcher._

  override def persistenceId = "task-dispatcher-persistence-ID"

  // Actor State
  var endpoints: Map[String, ActorRef] = Map()


  def receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case AddEndpoint(serverEndpoint, id) =>
      endpoints += (id -> serverEndpoint)

  }

  def receiveCommand: Receive = {

    case AddEndpoint(serverEndpoint, id) =>
      log.info("AddEndpoint received")
      persistAsync(AddEndpoint(serverEndpoint, id)) { command =>
        endpoints += (id -> serverEndpoint)
      }
  }

}
```

I create an instance of the PersistedActor and I send a message AddEndpoint to it through another actor

```
val taskDispatcher =
    context.actorOf(Props[TaskDispatcher], "task-dispatcher")
taskDispatcher ! AddEndpoint(self, id)
```

Before I had a non- persistent version of this actor and everything worked. Now the actor doesn't receive AddEndpoint message. I noticed it because log doesn't print "AddEndpoint received" message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which journal are you using? Are you sure it is working (db available etc)?

Comment: I'm using MongoDb. I don't know which journal I'm using. How can i check it? however I tried ExamplePersistentActor downloaded from typesafe and it seems tp work.

Comment: Which dependency did you include to connect akka to mongo, ironfish ( https://github.com/ironfish/akka-persistence-mongo )?

Comment: I didn't have any dependency to connect akka to mongo. I have just put now   "com.github.ironfish" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-casbah"  % "0.7.5" % "compile" in build.sbt but it still doesn't work (No command AddEndpoint received)

Comment: Can you check starts recovery or not? Just place  `log.info` into `receiveRecover`.

Comment: I placed log.info("receiverRecover") and recovery doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just recovery doesn't start. Try place:

```
override def preStart() = {
  self ! Recover()
}
```

Comment: Now it works! Thanks! Do you know why should I send Recover inside preStart()? By reading documentation I understood that Recovery starts after a failure (e.g. the actor throws an Exception). But in this case no exception is thrown. Have I misunderstood the documentation?

Comment: Recovery starts when a persistent actor is created (could be after a failure), and is based on its `persistenceId`.

Comment: @MattiaMicomonaco, a persistent actor save it state on a disk and recover it after start or restart (after fault). It just read all saved messages one by one from a disk and send theirs in `receiveRecover`. Documentation said that recovering starts automatically, but in your case it not happened (I don't know why). If you not need recovery just write `override def preStart() = {}`. I don't know how you recovery `ActorRef` after start `TaskDispatcher`. I think, it will not work.